# How to get the count of records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am fetching the records by date say

`db.Commercial_Auto.find({ "session.@Datestamp": {'$regex':'2016-05-03'}})`

Added to the date I want to get the count of records.

Do we have any syntax for count?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a good idea to store date as `date`, not as `string`. `$regex` does give you result, but not as efficiently as you think. At least should try:

```
db.Commercial_Auto.find({ "session.@Datestamp": {'$regex':'^2016-05-03'}})  // note the ^ makes it be able to hit index if any
```

I would suggest you to convert your field to `date` for further usage, try:

```
db.Commercial_Auto.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
  db.COmmercial_Auto.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {"session.@Datestamp", doc['session']['@Datestamp']}});
});
```

Get back to you question, the `count`. `find` returns a cursor, which enables you to invoke `count` from it and get the result:

```
db.Commercial_Auto.find({ "session.@Datestamp": {'$regex':'^2016-05-03'}}).count();
```

or you can use

```
db.Commercial_Auto.count({ "session.@Datestamp": {'$regex':'^2016-05-03'}})
```

which is a shortcut of first statement.
Also note in a sharded cluster, count probably won't give you an accurate number but a rough one. see [document about count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters).